# Understanding the definition of left homotopy as given in Quillen’s Homotopical algebra book

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories

Given two topological spaces $X,Y$, and two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$, there is a notion of homotopy between $f$ and $g$. It is given by a continuous map $H:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ such that the composition $H\circ i_0$ gives $f$ and $H\circ i_1$ gives $g$, where $i_0,i_1$ are what you expect it to be.

Quillen defines left homotopy in the following way:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a model category. Let $f,g:A\rightarrow B$ be maps. We say that, $f$ is left homotopic to $g$ if there is a diagram of the form [image]

where $\sigma$ is a weak equivalence.

Only after comparing with the notion of homotopy in topological spaces, it can be guessed that they are referring to homotopy as the map $h:\widetilde{A}\rightarrow B$ (as in case of topological spaces, we had a map $A\times I\rightarrow B$). The above condition of $H\circ i_0$ gives $f$ and $H\circ i_1$ gives $g$, seems to be combined in just one diagram (upper triangle) by saying $h\circ (\partial_0+\partial_1)=f+g$. Though it is not very clear, it looks like this  is the case.

But, then, there would be no need to mention the map $\sigma$. So, May be the notion of left homotopy is given by not just one morphism, but by a pair of morphisms $(\sigma, h)$ where $\sigma$ is a map from the “special object” to $A$ and $h$ is (the usual, as in the case of topological spaces) a map from the “special object” to $B$. Then, there is a map $\partial_0+\partial_1:A\wedge A\rightarrow \widetilde{A}$. I think it it safe to think this as a pair of maps $(\partial_0:A\rightarrow\widetilde{A}, \partial_1: A\rightarrow\widetilde{A})$. Thus it looks like a left homotopy is a $5$-tuple, out of which, one is an object $\widetilde{A}$, and the other 4 are maps,

$$(\partial_0:A\rightarrow\widetilde{A}, \partial_1: A\rightarrow\widetilde{A}, \sigma: \widetilde{A}\rightarrow A, h:\widetilde{A}\rightarrow B)$$
satisfying certain conditions.

Question :

1. Did I understood correctly? Or, did I misunderstand some part?
2. In case of topological spaces, there is no notion of left or right homotopy. But, in this case, what was the justification for introduction of left and right notion. In case of topological spaces, there is no notion similar to $\sigma$. What is the justification to introduce the extra data here.
3. Why is it done differently in the recent books?

Comment: I think you would probably benefit from reading a more didactic exposition of model categories to help you appreciate why Quillen makes these definitions and how they are related to the more classical ones for topological spaces, which is probably too much for a brief answer.  The easiest source I know of is Dwyer-Spalinski's "Homotopy theory and model categories", available here: https://math.jhu.edu/~eriehl/616-s16/DwyerSpalinski.pdf

Comment: @AndyPutman Thansk for the suggestion of that book. I will see that.. I thought the answer for part 2 would not be so simple.. do you have any thing to say for 1 and 3?

Comment: So I think that the fact that you are asking #3 means that you have misunderstood the point of model categories.  It's not that "more recent" books (by which I assume you mean more recent books on topology) define things differently.  Rather, what Quillen is doing is setting up a machine that works in a vast number of cases beyond simply topological spaces.  It wouldn't make sense for a book like Hatcher to write things model-categorically since he is only interested in spaces themselves, not more general things.  Again: read Dwyer-Spalinski.

Comment: @AndyPutman I am in initial stages of understanding model categories… I think misunderstanding comes in first half of understanding something… :) I will read that notes.

Comment: @AndyPutman I think you misunderstood what I mean.. “ It's not that "more recent" books (by which I assume you mean more recent books on topology) define things differently. ”..  I don’t mean topology books. I mean books on model categories.. and also in the n-lab..

Comment: Do they define things differently?  I avoid the n-lab since I've never found their explanations useful (it's like they apply a one-way filter to comprehensible mathematics, turning it into something that makes no sense).  But all the sources I've read seem more-or-less the same.  It might help if you spell out exactly what you think the differences are.

Comment: Here is one remark that might help you.  The purpose of $\widetilde{A}$ is to be a replacement for $A \times I$.  So for topological spaces, the maps he gives are the obvious ones, e.g. $\sigma\colon A \times I \rightarrow A$ is the projection onto the first factor, and the two maps $\partial_i\colon A \rightarrow A \times I$ are the inclusions onto $A \times 0$ and $A \times 1$.  He's trying to sort out exactly what properties you need from these obvious maps when you generalize to other settings.

Comment: @AndyPutman yes, that is helpful. So, in case of topological spaces, the 3 out of 4 maps I mentioned above are obvious. So, we mention only one map; the homotopy map. Different in the sense all of them first discuss the notion of cylinder object and then talk about left homotopy… nlab page is https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+in+a+model+category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation you need to make sense of Quillen's definition is that $\tilde{A}$ is "the [cylinder object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cylinder+object) on A." In topological spaces, that's $I\times A$ but not every model category has an interval object like $I$, so we wouldn't want to specify this particular definition of a cylinder object. It's better to be more general, and let the cylinder object be any object $\tilde{A}$ fitting in a factorization of $\nabla: A\vee A \to A$ into a cofibration followed by a trivial fibration.

In Top, you can also define homotopy via the "[path space object](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/path+space+object)" $Y^I$, i.e., the space of paths in $Y$. But, for a general model category without an interval I, it's better to define the path space object as a factorization of the diagonal map $X\to X\times X$ into a trivial cofibration followed by a fibration.

A priori, these two definitions of homotopy could be different, hence calling the first one "left homotopy" and the second one "right homotopy." It's a theorem that if $M$ is actually a model category, then these two notions of homotopy coincide. But, for any old category with chosen classes of morphisms called weak equivalences, cofibrations, and fibrations, they wouldn't have to coincide.

Being a student of Mark Hovey, I have to recommend [his book on model categories](https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/doug/otherpapers/hovey-model-cats.pdf), which spells this out in general and also for topological spaces.

Comment: I will add that the choice of the map $\sigma$ is not very important. There might be many weak equivalences $\sigma$, and the notion of homotopy you get does not depend on which $(\tilde{A},\sigma)$ you choose, up to homotopy (in this case, homotopy between homotopies). What matters is that $\sigma$ is a weak equivalence and $d_0+d_1$ is a cofibration.

Comment: Ok. I tried reading Mark Hovey in last year.. someone said it has so many typos. Would you recommend for some one who is reading on own without any background or local support..

Comment: The newest book on model categories is by Scott Balchin and is great: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-75035-0

Comment: Oh. Ok. Thanks. I have heard name of the author in some other situation.. did not knew about his book. Many thanks. I will see that..

Comment: Just for use of other people, homotopy between two maps $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ can be seen as a map $H:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ or as a map $G:X\rightarrow Y^I$.. the object $X\times I$ is called the cylinder object associated to $X$ and the object $Y^I$ is called the path space object associated to $Y$.. it is not very common to talk about homotopy using path space object..